# No config-pin binary when creating custom kernel image in yocto for beaglebone black

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack

Thank you for reading this thread, I have recently started a personal project using Beaglebone black.
I wanted to create a custom kernel image with the config-pin binary included but all the images I've created so far doesn't have it. https://beagleboard.org/latest-images already has built images and I have confirmed config-pin is working correctly however I wanted to build the image on my own using Yocto because I will have to modify the kernel driver source code in the future (remove some modules to reduce boot-up time).

Does the config-pin binary already included in the Linux kernel source code and that I only have to enable it in menuconfig or is it something like an add-on board support package (BSP) that I will have to add in yocto layers?

The bottom line of this question is how to create a kernel image in yocto that is identical to the one beaglebone.org releases? (or at least it has the config-pin binary)

I tried to create the following images:
core-image-base
core-image-full-cmdline
core-image-sato-dev

I was expecting the dev type image to include the config-pin binary but I was wrong.

My plan is to try create a **core-image-sato-sdk** image but my guess is that config-pin binary is still not included since the difference of dev and sdk image is only the cross-toolchain.

Another solution I can think of is maybe get the defconfig file in the already built image from Beaglebone and use it as my defconfig file when building my image in yocto? I am not sure if it will work though.

I kindly need your help, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OpenEmbedded Layer Index](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/) to find more about layers and recipes.

To develop around the `beaglebone` you can search for `beagle` in the machine list. For the `kirkstone` branch of Yocto, `meta-ti-bsp` provides the [beaglebone](https://git.yoctoproject.org/meta-ti/tree/meta-ti-bsp/conf/machine/beaglebone.conf?h=kirkstone) machine.

Which has the following lines:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-bb.org"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/bootloader = "u-boot-bb.org"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot = "u-boot-bb.org"

KERNEL_DEVICETREE_PREFIX = "am335x-bone"

KERNEL_DEVICETREE = " \
    am335x-bone.dtb \
    am335x-boneblue.dtb \
    am335x-boneblack.dtb \
    am335x-boneblack-wireless.dtb \
    am335x-bonegreen.dtb \
    am335x-bonegreen-wireless.dtb \
"
```

And it set's the kernel to be used to the `linux-bb.org` kernel which is the [BeagleBoard.org Linux kernel](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/333122/). And the bootloader to be BeagleBoard.org U-Boot.

So this would be a start in using the beagleboard kernel by specifying that you are building for the `beaglebone` machine. Different versions of `Yocto` e.g. `kirkstone` or `dunfell` may build different versions of the beagleboard kernel.

Now a complete image would contain a bootloader, a kernel as well as a root filesystem. Using `meta-ti-bsp` should provide the bootloader, kernel as well as the device tree you need to load in at the u-boot shell.

For any supplementary programs you will have to find a Yocto recipe that provides it or create your own recipe to build the program from it's source.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just a quick question, will I have to consider what branch of Yocto I will be using (dunfell or kirkstone)? Currently I just got the latest version from their site https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/downloads/ and the version I got is Mickledore. Why are there many versions of Yocto and are some layers only compatible to a specific Yocto version/branch?

Comment: @KUJI Yocto releases on a 6month cycle, with some versions such as `dunfell` being a long term support version. Both dunfell and Kirkstone should have support until April 2024. For the most part you want to look at the layers you need and what they provide. For example [TI here](https://git.ti.com/cgit/arago-project/meta-ti/) have different branches, and they have kirkstone and dunfell. If master will work with Micklemore I am not sure. So for Instance I am using a TI board and I saw it has support in kirkstone but not in dunfell so I am using the kirkstone branch for what I need.

Comment: @KUJI But once you pick a branch, all the layers that you then add should also be on that same branch. You will find other meta layers will have similar branch names like kirkstone which you can then checkout once you git clone them into your desktop environment. You will find syntactical differences between `kirkstone` and `dunfell` in things like your local.conf file which you can [see here](https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Override_syntax_change_from_Yocto_honister_3.4)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was able to build a kernel with meta-ti-bsp layer included, only problem now is that it cannot boot-up due to no partition table in mmc 0

Comment: @KUJI No worries, if you flashed your `core-image-.....rootfs.wic.xz` file onto the SD card, you should most likely have two partitions on your SD card, a boot partition and a root filesystem. If you can boot up into the `u-boot` shell but not into the kernel you will have to configure your `u-boot` environment, which you can see with commands like `printenv` or `printenv bootcmd` to see what the default boot command is. You might have better luck on the TI forums or beaglebone forums for help on setting up u-boot.

Comment: Yeah I used core-image-.....rootfs.wic.xz which already has a pre-partitioned image but I encountered kernel panic, not sure though what is the cause of this:
"Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)"

Comment: @KUJI like I mentioned, you have to set up the parameters on how to boot into the kernel correctly and this is done in the u-boot shell.